# Javascript function cant figure it out

Tags: javascript, function

```
function isSimple(number) {
    for (let i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false
    }
    return true
}

function range(min, max) {
    for (let i = min;i < max; i++) {
        if(isSimple(i))
        document.write(`${i} <br>`);
    }
}
console.log(range(2, 100));
```

Please explain why you need to write if(isSimple(i)) in function range, not isSimple(i), how does it work ?

Comment: How do you expect `isSimple(i)` without `if` to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isSimple` returns a boolean type response. The logic in `range` only wants to output the value if it is simple, so it's using `if` for this.  In this form of `if` the next statement is considered the scope of the `if` block.

You could expand this out to this equivalent code that might be easier to understand:

```js
function range(min, max) {
    for (let i = min;i < max; i++) {
        if (isSimple(i) === true) {
          document.write(`${i} <br>`);
        }
    }
}
```

This makes the comparison more explicit, and uses `{...}` to clearly delimit which statement(s) are conditionally executed when the `if` condition evaluates to `true`.